# Why does Mongoose setClient return MongooseError: Must call `setClient()` with an instance of MongoClient?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble getting `setClient()` to work. My understanding of this is, that I can make a connection to MongoDB with the native MongoDB MongoClient and then in another piece of code I should be able to use this instance of the MongoClient to connect to Mongoose. So set the client to Mongoose while using the same identical connection, not a separate one.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-setClient

> Set the MongoDB driver MongoClient instance that this connection uses to talk to MongoDB. This is useful if you already have a MongoClient instance, and want to reuse it.

**Case A**

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

async function run() {
    try {
        const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

        // Create a new MongoClient
        const client = new MongoClient(uri);

        const conn = mongoose.createConnection().setClient(client);

        conn.getClient(); // MongoClient { ... }
        conn.readyState; // 1, means 'CONNECTED'

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
run();
```

This returns
`MongooseError: Must call setClient() with an instance of MongoClient at NativeConnection.setClient (.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:1391:11)`.

Why am I getting this error ? What is the correct code for `setClient()`?

**Case B**
Vercel shows how to used MongoDB and Mongoose in their environment exporting a `clientPromise` here with MongoDB https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js and a `dbConnect` here with Mongoose https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/lib/dbConnect.js.

So given in `db.js` I have this exemplary code with the native MongoDB driver

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = {}

let client
let clientPromise

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local')
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  clientPromise = client.connect()
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise
```

and in another file I like to use this `clientPromise` with Mongoose what do I do ?

Is my understanding correct here that I in fact **can** use the exported MongoDB `clientPromise` with Mongoose at all through the use of `setClient()` ? *Or is `setClient()` used for something different ?*

In another file, if I try this

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import clientPromise from '$lib/mongodb';

export async function get() {
    try {
        const client = await clientPromise;

        console.log(client); // logs client just fine

        const conn = mongoose.createConnection().setClient(client);
        // starts complaining here with
        // MongooseError: Must call `setClient()` with an instance of MongoClient

        conn.getClient(); // MongoClient { ... }
        conn.readyState; // 1, means 'CONNECTED'

        console.log(conn);

        return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                message: 'ok'
            }
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

the same error is shown.

How do I get `setClient()` to work on either, the `MongoClient` instance or the `clientPromise`?

edit:
I also get this error.
`Argument of type 'import(".../node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").MongoClient' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import(".../node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").MongoClient'.`

`The types of 'options.credentials' are incompatible between these types.`

`Type 'import(".../node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").MongoCredentials' is not assignable to type 'import(".../node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").MongoCredentials'.`